# How to format a js date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing this code but it seems I don't get the result I want. This is a Real Time Clock.

```
<p id="time"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTime(){
  $('#time').html(new Date());
}

$(function(){
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
});
</script>
```

This is the Result:

```
Tue Aug 15 2017 13:34:09 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

How Can I format the Date and Time to this: `"Tue August 15, 2017 1:30pm"`

Comment: I'm kinda sure this has been answered multiple times on SO, what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Formatting dates in Javascript is pretty limited. For any type of custom date formatting you could check out [moment.js](https://momentjs.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

Using [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) this is easy to achieve

```
var dt = moment([2015, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
dt.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); //Prints "Sunday, February 14th 2015, 3:25:50 pm"
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine.. I am now using moment.js ... how can I set timezone?

Comment: var dt = moment([2015, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50, 125]).tz('America/Phoenix'); Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `toDateString()` and `toLocaleTimeString()`：

```
var now = new Date(); // Tue Aug 15 2017 14:05:13 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
var date = now.toDateString(); // "Tue Aug 15 2017"
var time = now.toLocaleTimeString(); // "下午2:05:13"
var flag = time.indexOf('下午') === 0 ? 'pm' : 'am';
time = time.slice(2) + flag; // "2:08:52pm"
console.log(date + ' ' + time); // "Tue Aug 15 2017 2:08:52pm"
```